# Problema de CORS en servicio WCF

Tags: javascript, cors, wcf

Tengo un aplicación que contiene un servicio WCF, el servicio responde de manera correcta cuando realizo las pruebas en la herramienta de pruebas del visual studio y también responde manera correcta cuando lo pruebo en Insomnia, sin embargo, cuando intento llamar al servicio desde mi aplicación de react esta no responde y me regresa el siguiente error:

Access to fetch at 'http://miURL' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Entiendo que es un problema de CORS por el origen de la petición, sin embargo, no entiendo en donde ni como tengo que configurar el servicio WCF para que el error deje de salir.

Esta es mi petición:

```
const test = async () => {
    const peticion = await fetch('URL', {
            method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
    })
    const respuesta = await peticion.json()
    console.log(respuesta);
  }
```

Mi código Service:

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public string leerHuella()
    {
        Form1 form1 = new Form1();
        string value = form1.leerHuellaForm();
        return value;
    }
}
```

Mi código iService:

```
public interface IService1

    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet]
        string leerHuella();
    }
```

Mi configuración de comportamiento de mi archivo App.config:

```
<endpointBehaviors>
  <behavior name="jsonBehavior">
    <enableWebScript />
  </behavior>
</endpointBehaviors>
```

Si alguien pudiera decirme en donde y como configurar el servicio, sería genial.

Comment: Comparte el código para que te podamos ayudar.

Comment: Hola, ya he agregado el código a la pregunta